# Implementation of ripple transformation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transform

Ripple transformation is a nonlinear image warp, in a photo the formula is given:
[image: Ripple transformation]
My implementation is like follows:

```
function y = rippleTransform(I, t1, t2, t3, t4)

[m,n] = size(I);

for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        if round(i+t3*sin((2*pi*j)/t1)) > 0 && round(j+t4*sin((2*pi*i/t2))) > 0
            T(round(i+t3*sin((2*pi*j)/t1)), round(j+t4*sin((2*pi*i)/t2))) = I(i,j);
        end
    end
end
y = T;
end
```

But the result is not as it is expected to be. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

When you perform a geometric transform on an image you want to do a reverse mapping. Effectively you want to iterate through the pixels in the output image and sample the correct location from the source image. That's why the assignment gives the inverse transform rather than the forward transform.

One thing you need to consider is that the sampling coordinates in the source image may not be integral values so we perform interpolation to estimate image intensity "between" pixels.

```
function T = rippleTransform(I, tx, ty, ax, ay)
    [x,y] = meshgrid(1:size(I,2),1:size(I,1));
    u = x + ax*sin(2*pi*y/tx);
    v = y + ay*sin(2*pi*x/ty);
    T = cast(interp2(x,y,double(I),u,v),class(I));
end
```

**Example**

```
>> I = imread('rice.png');
>> T = rippleTransform(I, 120, 250, 10, 15);
```

[image]